# Parsing file or streaming input with feedzirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, rss, feedzirra

I've to "parse" a Rails "request.body" on the fly, something like :

```
  feed = Feedzirra::Feed.parse(request.body.read)
  feed.entries do |entry|
    entry.title      # => "Ruby Http Client Library Performance"
    entry.url        # => "http://www.pauldix.net/2009/01/ruby-http-client-library-performance.html"
    entry.author     # => "Paul Dix"
    entry.summary    # => "..."
    entry.content    # => "..."
    entry.published  # => Thu Jan 29 17:00:19 UTC 2009 # it's a Time object
    entry.categories # => ["...", "..."]
  end
```

Is it possible?  Should be similar to get a streaming input or reading from a file, don't you think so?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What does request.body contain?

Comment: I didn't get anything at all ..., I'll check thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... the code was right, as well as the way of parsing, what I missed was the "output" ;-)

Adding "puts", I get the values on the fly ( while I'm getting http POST into "request.body" ):

```
feed = Feedzirra::Feed.parse(request.body.read)
  feed.entries.each do |entry|
    puts entry.title      # => "Ruby Http Client Library Performance"
    puts entry.url        # => "http://www.pauldix.net/2009/01/ruby-http-client-library-performance.html"
    puts entry.author     # => "Paul Dix"
    puts entry.summary    # => "..."
    puts entry.content    # => "..."
    puts entry.published  # => Thu Jan 29 17:00:19 UTC 2009 # it's a Time object
    puts entry.categories # => ["...", "..."]
  end
```

Thanks Christopher Manning for suggestions ...